# How to install Kotlin in Ubuntu 16.04 using snap?

Tags: 16.04, snap

It says on the official website that we can install it on 16.04 and later using the following command:
`$ sudo snap install --classic kotlin`

But when I run the command, the following error shows up :

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/kotlin: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

How to fix this?

Comment: Sounds like the snap daemon isn't running.

Comment: Thomas Ward, how can I start it?

Comment: A reboot might do it.  You could try `sudo service snapd start`.  then check syslog for any errors to determine if snapd is having issues starting.

Comment: I rebooted and tried but it didn't start. Also, I tried the command to start snapd but it gave this error message:`Job for snapd.socket failed.
See "systemctl status snapd.socket" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Failed to start snapd.service: Unit snapd.service is masked.
`

Comment: Here is the output of `systemctl status snapd` :  
 `snapd.service

   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)

   Active: inactive (dead)
`
and for `snap version` :

`snap    2.37.4

snapd   unavailable

series  -
`